# Bot integration in Outlook (Office 365)

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, artificial-intelligence, bots

Is it possible to develop a chatbot with a possible voice integration (maybe Cortana somehow) with the Microsoft Bot Framework and integrate it in Outlook (mail, calendar, tasks)? I started looking at some resources

https://dev.outlook.com/Videos#outlook-addins

but cannot decide where I should look in particular. Can someone provide me with a good start in terms of reading material?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create bots the botframework is the place to start, https://dev.botframework.com. Here you can create bots that interact with a chatclient. To understand text LUIS.AI (https://luis.ai) is startpoint. LUIS translates utterances into intents (what does user want) and entities (with what parameters).

LUIS.AI has a number of pre-created application that act about Outlook (move appointment of 3 o'clock to 4)

For cortana you can now only build UWP App that integrate your App with Cortana using Speech. Sample can be found at: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand

If you want to have speech and transform it to text you can use cognitive services of Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api

Hope this helps
Sander